# How Can I Set Up Prometheus And Gorm in Golang?

Tags: docker, go, prometheus, go-gorm

I'm trying to connect GORM and Prometheus. When I look up the gorm docs, they gave just configs but I couldn't find instructions.

I set up exactly they told but can't execute that.

```golang
dsn := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s user=%s password=%s dbname=%s port=%s sslmode=%s TimeZone=%s", os.Getenv("DB_HOST"), os.Getenv("DB_USER"), os.Getenv("DB_PASS"), os.Getenv("DB_NAME"), os.Getenv("DB_PORT"), os.Getenv("DB_SSL_MODE"), os.Getenv("DB_TIMEZONE"))
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{
        DisableForeignKeyConstraintWhenMigrating: true,
        Logger:                                   logger.Default.LogMode(logger.Info),
    })
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    db.Use(prometheus.New(prometheus.Config{
        DBName:          "postgres", 
        RefreshInterval: 15,    
        PushAddr:        "idk what's pusher", 
        StartServer:     true,  
        HTTPServerPort:  8080,  
        MetricsCollector: []prometheus.MetricsCollector {
            &prometheus.Postgres{
                VariableNames: []string{"Threads_running"},
            },
        },  // user defined metrics
    }))
```

and my compose files.

```yaml
prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    container_name: prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
    ports:
      - 9190:9090
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - asd
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus:/etc/prometheus
      - prom_data:/prometheus
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    container_name: grafana
    ports:
      - 3001:3000
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - asd
    environment:
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER=admin
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=grafana
    volumes:
      - ./grafana:/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources
```

Can you describe other steps?

Comment: Does your go application already have an http server that serves the metrics under e.g. `/metrics`? if yes `db.Use(prometheus.New(prometheus.Config{
  DBName:          config.Database,  })` should already be sufficient for basic metrics

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 nope no metric

Comment: Do I need to create metrics endpoint

Comment: I guess so. I am aware of an interface for pushing metrics to prometheus, but I am not sure if GORM implements that.